# getBackStackEntryCount return 0 when Activity is recreated

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know this has to be simple and I'm probably not seeing the solution.
Here is the brief description of what I have:
SignInActivity(AppCompatActivity) - handle the Firebase authentication, on success calls the method:

```
private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
    // Go to MainActivity
    startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

MainActivity(AppCompatActivity) - handle the menus for the application, this menu in particular are fragments with buttons. When a button is clicked I change the fragment that contains other buttons. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_left)
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContent, MainMenuFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow();
    }

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new 
        FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                int stackHeight = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(stackHeight > 0);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(stackHeight > 0);
            }
        });
}

public void replaceFragments(Class fragmentClass, boolean isBack) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    if (isBack) {
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    } else {
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fragment = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContent, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(fragmentClass.getName());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

MainMenuFragment(Fragment) - First set of options, several buttons on top of each other. Depending on the button clicked will call MainActivity.replaceFragment passing the next Fragment to go.

```
public class MainMenuFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MainMenuFragment";

    public static MainMenuFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainMenuFragment();
    }

    public MainMenuFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);

        final Button btnAssets = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAssets);
        final Button btnAudit = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAudit);

        btnAssets.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "BtnAssets_onClick");
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragments(AssetMenuFragment.class);
            }
        });

        btnAudit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "BtnAudit_onClick");
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragments(AuditMenuFragment.class);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

The AssetMenuFragment and the AuditMenuFragment are pretty much the same as the MainMenu, only the text for the buttons and some layout details changes.

When I'm using the app I first signIn, which leads me to the MainActivity, which loads the MainMenuFragment on onCreate. There I'm presented with two buttons, one to go to the AssetMenuFragment and the other to go to the AuditMenuFragment, they replace the fragment with their according layouts.
If I click the Asset button, once the fragment is replaced, because of:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(stackHeight > 0);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(stackHeight > 0);
```

I'm presented with the back arrow to go back to MainMenuFragment. Everything works as expected.

Now the problem! If I'm in this AssetMenuFragment, with my beautiful back arrow showing on the ActionBar and decided to click the "Square" button on the device, which is probably run the onPause and onStop, and them click on the app again, which will run the onCreate and onStart again, my back arrow disappears, because now `int stackHeight = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();` is zero.

How can I save my stack and restore it later so I can press back on the AssetMenuFragment and go back to MainMenuFragment.

It is a lot to read, but I'll appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I knew it had to be something simple.

Both checks are correct.

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(stackHeight > 0);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(stackHeight > 0);
```

The problem was that I didn't check for them on onCreate, only on the `getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener` event.

Here is the MainActivity now:

```
private ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContent, MainMenuFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow();
    }

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    updateActionBarBackButton();

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new 
        FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                updateActionBarBackButton();
            }
        });
}

private void updateActionBarBackButton() {
    int stackHeight = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(stackHeight > 0);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(stackHeight > 0);
}
```